# How to hide SIM number when sending SMS via AT commands?

Tags: sms, at-command

How can I change or hide SIM number, is there a way to do it via AT commands or doing something?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean, perhaps add an example? When you've done that flag to re-open. Thanks.